# excel web part doesn't edit when i opened the page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, excel

I have a SharePoint page with an excel Web Part. But, when I try to edit the page, the page is not opening in edit mode (It keep spinning). Any idea how to fix this issue??? Thanks for your help

N.B I have a full permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's specifically the main reason for this issue!  Meanwhile, to be able to edit your page, you can close the Excel web part during modifying your page then add it again after you finish the page edit.

**To close a web part**

- Open your page > In the address bar > add at the end of URL `?contents=1` for example: `http://site/page.aspx?contents=1`
- The maintenance page should be now opened > select your web part then select close.

[image]

- Go back to your page > edit it as you need > and before stop editing > add the closed web part again as shown below

[image]